# Method to create username after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still not terribly good at creating my own methods in Ruby/Rails. I am simply looking to insert data into my "username" field using an after_save callback.

I want to create the username from the email that gets input at registration. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
after_save :create_username
def create_username
    self.username = self.email.split('@').first
end
```

I want the username to be everything before the @ sign in the email field that the user submits during registration.

I know the RegEx of: ^[^-]* will work too, but I am not sure how I'd incorporate a RegEx into a function.

I think using after_save would be the proper callback, but please recommend something else if I am wrong.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a `regex`

```
email = "someguy@example.com"
@username = email.gsub(/@.*/,'')
# => "someguy"
```

As far as your implementation goes. I would not build out a product in a way where your users' username is their email **because people value their privacy**. You also don't need a `after_save` callback. That doesn't make sense here.

You can just get the `email` from your `db` and run the above code on it which will allow you to call `@username` from your views.

Comment: Valid point about their privacy, might change it to first initial, last name. It is really just a placeholder for a profile URL. Also good to know about the after_save callback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use when I handled usernames the same way.

```
after_save :create_username

protected

def create_username
  username = email[/(.*)@.*/, 1]
end
```

The `self` object can be omitted as ruby assumes you meant to call a method on `self` if no object is referenced.

Another option is:

```
email.match(/(.*)@.*/)[1]
```

Lots of choices :)